# fwrite writes garbage value to file

Tags: c, fwrite

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct struct_type
{
  int d;
};

int main()
{

  struct struct_type *cust;

  cust->d=13;

  FILE* fp;

  fp = fopen("path to file", "wb+");

  or,

  fp = fopen("path to file", "w+");     

  fwrite(cust, sizeof(struct struct_type), 1, fp);

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;

}
```

**Expected output**

13

However getting garbage value written to file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you had allocated memory for `cust`, or used a plain struct instead of a pointer, you'd get a file that contains the *binary* representation of the int 13 on your platform. Which would be unreadable in, say, notepad.

If you look at the output in a hex editor, you'll see a few zero bytes and one `0xOD` - number of zero bytes depends on the size of ints on your platform, and whether they'll be before or after the 13 byte depends on its endianness.

If you want a file with `13` as text in it, use `fprintf`.

(Since you haven't allocated memory, your program has undefined behavior, and can do anything at all.)

---

Fix with a struct on stack:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct struct_type
{
  int d;
};

int main()
{
  struct struct_type cust;
  cust.d=13;

  FILE* fp;
  fp = fopen("path_to_file", "wb+");
  fwrite(&cust, sizeof(cust), 1, fp);
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic t.c
$ ./a.out 
$ hexdump -C path_to_file 
00000000  0d 00 00 00                                       |....|
00000004
```

To get a text file instead, replace the `fwrite` with:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d", cust.d); // or "%d\nd";
```

and drop the "b" from the open mode since that's for binary I/O.

Answer (score 2):

Allocate menory to your structure pointer `cust`

`fwrite(cust, sizeof(struct struct_type), 1, fp);`

Writes Binary data Into file.

The data which is present is binary data, that is Not garbage.

if you want to see whether it writes correctly or not read into object and print.

Use `fread()`

other wise convert integer to string and write into a text file.

Then you can able to see 13.

Comment: yes thanks that's the case but the data is same whether i use w+ or wb+ +1 for the answer

Comment: `w` mode truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.  `wb` mode truncate file to zero length or create binary file for writing.The character 'b' shall have no effect, but is allowed for ISO C standard conformance. see [fopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html) and [here also](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/)