# fread/fwrite a struct to/from a file in C

Tags: c

I'm having troubles using the fread/fwrite functions to read and write structures to a file. First of all, text written by fwrite is unreadable for me, but from what I see, it is intended to work like this. Is there a way to make it plain text, or it has to be like that?

The other problem is that when I try to read from that file using the fread function, few last elements aren't read.

Further, I'll need this piece of code to sort, directly on the disk, data from a file. Usage of fread/fwrite is compulsory..

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct camesi {
    char camasa[33];
    char culoare[33];
    int marime;
    char material[33];
} cam;

int main() {

    FILE *f, *f2;
    int i, j, n;
    cam a, b, c;

    n = 13;

    f  = fopen ("new.txt", "w+");
    f2 = fopen ("asd.txt", "r");
    rewind (f2);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fscanf (f2, "%s%s%d%s", c.camasa, c.culoare, &c.marime, c.material);
        printf ("%s\t%s\t%d\t%s\n", c.camasa, c.culoare, c.marime, c.material);
        fwrite (&c, sizeof (cam), 1, f);
    }

    printf ("\n----------------------------------------\n\n");

    rewind (f);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fread (&c, sizeof (cam), 1, f);
        printf ("%s\t%s\t%d\t%s\n", c.camasa, c.culoare, c.marime, c.material);
    }

return 0; }
```

This is the output to console:

```
asdf1   blue    45      skin
asdf2   green   43      skin
asdf3   white   49      skin
asdf4   red     47      skin
asdf5   yellow  54      skin
asdf6   purple  13      skin
asdf7   magenta 74      skin
asdf8   pink    41      skin
asdf9   black   97      skin
asdf10  gray    85      skin
asdf11  orange  26      skin
asdf12  violet  64      skin
asdf13  brown   11      skin

----------------------------------------

asdf1   blue    45      skin
asdf2   green   43      skin
asdf3   white   49      skin
asdf4   red     47      skin
asdf5   yellow  54      skin
asdf6   purple  13      skin
asdf7   magenta 74      skin
asdf8   pink    41      skin
asdf9   black   97      skin
asdf10  gray    85      skin
asdf11  orange  85      skin
asdf11  orange  85      skin
asdf11  orange  85      skin
```

The first half is the data read from a manually created *.txt file.

The other half is the data read from a file created with the program, using fwrite function.

Content of the original *.txt file:

```
asdf1   blue    45  skin
asdf2   green   43  skin
asdf3   white   49  skin
asdf4   red 47  skin
asdf5   yellow  54  skin
asdf6   purple  13  skin
asdf7   magenta 74  skin
asdf8   pink    41  skin
asdf9   black   97  skin
asdf10  gray    85  skin
asdf11  orange  26  skin
asdf12  violet  64  skin
asdf13  brown   11  skin
```

Content of the file created with fwrite function:

```
asdf1   €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяblue           M             -   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf2   €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяgreen          M             +   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf3   €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяwhite          M             1   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf4   €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяred e          M             /   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf5   €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяyellow         M             6   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf6   €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяpurple         M             
   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf7   €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяmagenta        M             J   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf8   €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяpink ta        M             )   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf9   €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяblack a        M             a   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf10  €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяgray  a        M             U   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf11  €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяorange         M                skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf12  €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяviolet         M             @   skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M asdf13  €M o  ёю(  Ђ(wїдЂ‚юяяяbrown          M                skin M `M      А&M €ю( HЯПt  M
```

Comment: You can switch to `fprintf` and `fscanf` functions if you want "readable" output. BTW. Sorting "directly on the disk" is a bad idea, unless you are absolutely short of RAM.

Comment: your structures don't clear out the extra characters in the `char[33]` fields when you write them, so they're full of whatever garbage was in that memory at the time.

Comment: the missing elements should be because some `fwrite()`s are still buffered. Call `fflush(f)` between writing and reading (and check the result of `fread()`)

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt that shouldn't be relevant - buffering only affects whether _other_ programs can see unflushed data.

Comment: @user4419802 unfortunately usage of fread/fwrite is compulsory, as well as sorting on the disk.. Doing everything with print and scan, and within RAM would make thing much easier, but the task I've received is restricted..

Comment: @Alnitak Is there a way to clean/empty  that extra junk?

Comment: Look at ***[memset()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fdeehz6.aspx)***

Comment: `memset(&c, 0, sizeof(c))`

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you, that cleaned most of the junk data, except for that **int**. I've changed that entry to char, and, to my surprise, changing it to char also solved the problem with reading last elements from file. But I can't understand how it is related..

Comment: Y do u need to read from asd.txt?

Comment: @YasirMajeed That is just a temporary sample that doesn't really fit the template properly for fwrite/fread 's understading.
The first part of the code, with fscanf, is to convert that data to fwrite/fread 's proper understanding. It'll be removed later.

Comment: Are you working on Windows? As you haven't open "new.txt" in binary mode, value 26 would written to the file as ^Z (plus some NULs) and then be interpreted as EOF

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Thank you, that fixed the issue with reading the data.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196083/fwrite-writes-garbage-value-to-file. `fwrite` is writing your int as a binary representation, you need to use `fprintf`

Comment: Instead of `fwrite (&c, sizeof (cam), 1, f);`, use `char buf[sizeof cam * 2]; sprintf(buf, "%s\t%s\t%d\t%s\n", c.camasa, c.culoare, c.marime, c.material); fwrite (buf, strlen(buf), 1, f);`

Comment: To be clear: What is the required format of `"new.txt"` 1) A text file with a variable width _line_ of information per each "cam" record. 2) A binary file with a fixed size record corresponding to the size of "cam" 3) something else?  I suspect #1.

Answer (score 0):

```
asdf11  orange  26  skin
```

windows  may regard 26 in the txt file as EOF

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make it plain text, or it has to be like that?

Yes, it has to be like that because when it was written, the file was filled with the data that was in memory. So it's always like this i.e. combination of readable and unreadable characters.

In order to understand the behavior of `fread/fwrite` i will take the example from your output

```
asdf1   blue    45      skin$asdf1   blue    45      skin$asdf1   blue    45      skin$asdf1   blue    45      skin$asdf1   blue    45      skin$asdf1   blue    45      skin$asdf1   blue    45      skin$
```

Now let suppose that the above code is in memory such that `asdf1   blue    45      skin` is a structure currently in memory. '$' is just a seperator to represent 7 structures residing in memory. Now if you want to read data from a file into a structure using fread, then the ideal situation is that the file the file was written using fwrite by writing each structure one by one, without any extra byte between them. Only then it can easily be read using fread().

To demonstrate this, here is a simple program that first fill 5 struct objects and then write them onto a file using fwrite. Then it again read those written structures from the file and then fill the C structures with that data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define MAX 5

struct camesi {
    char camasa[33];
    char culoare[33];
    int marime;
    char material[33];
} myStruct;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *file = NULL;

    //Fill a structure with values
    memset(&myStruct, 0, sizeof(myStruct));
    memcpy(myStruct.camasa, "asdf1", 5);
    memcpy(myStruct.culoare, "blue", 4);
    myStruct.marime = 45;
    memcpy(myStruct.material, "skin", 4);

    //Open the file to write
    if ((file = fopen("test.txt", "w+")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file to write\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        fwrite(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct), 1, file);

    fclose(file);

    //Open the file for read
    if ((file = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file for read\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Clear the myStruct from previous values
    memset(&myStruct, 0, sizeof(myStruct));

    //Read and display
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        fread(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct), 1, file);
        printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%s\n", myStruct.camasa, myStruct.culoare, myStruct.marime, myStruct.material);

        //Clear the myStruct from previous value as we will read again in same object in next iteration
        memset(&myStruct, 0, sizeof(myStruct));
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```